# react redux multiple http request dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, trello

I want to build a trello like application, and for this, I'm using a model for (board, list, and card) knowing that the list modal contains a boardID and the card model a listID, and I want to get my data from my API.

I'm using redux and this is my action, I basically get all boards for a user and I map through them to get their lists and then map through their list to get each list cards, I was wondering if it was the right thing to do.

especially when the dispatch action takes a little bit of time to get all the data and I finish rendering not all the data (even if after that the data is all here but comes late)

```
export const loadData = () => async (dispatch) => {

  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };
  try {
    axios.get("/api/board/").then((res) => {
      let boards = res.data;

      dispatch({
        type: GET_BOARDS,
        payload: boards,
      });
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ORDER_BOARD,
        payload: boards,
      });
      boards.forEach((board) => {
       
        axios.post("/api/table/", { boardId: board._id }, config).then((res) => {

          dispatch({
            type: GET_LISTS,
            payload: res.data,
          });
          dispatch({
            type: GET_LIST_BOARD,
            payload: res.data,
          });
          lists.forEach((list) => {
            axios
              .post("/api/card/", { listId: list._id }, config)
              .then((res) => {
                dispatch({
                  type: GET_CARDS,
                  payload: res.data,
                });
                dispatch({
                  type: GET_CARD_LIST,
                  payload: res.data,
                });
           
              });
          });
        });
      });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

If you are doing similar application to Trello, you don't need to fetch for everything in a single moment. When you are displaying list of boards, just fetch for boards. When you are displaying a single board, just fetch for data (tables/lists) of this board. Each table/list should fetch for their data (cards) in their own code.

I would do fetching in the "component way". Board component should fetch for its necessary data (board item data, which would contain a list of tables, but just their ids and some necessary properties), similarly a Table component and a Board component.

Then you can show for example loading overlays over individual components (or their [skeleton implementation](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/04/skeleton-screens-react/)) and not over whole page.